# Does Ping Identity set any environment variable containing the username of the person logged in?

Tags: environment-variables, ping, identity, pingfederate

I am trying to use this username in my code but I do not know if it is provided in the environment variables. Thanks!

Additional information: I am using using PingFederate and Ping One.
My website is based on C sharp and it used to get the windows environment variable for username. now I want it changed to the user logged in through ping identity.Is it possible to do so and in that case which SDK should I get (I am assuming the .net integration kit right?)?

Comment: that depends on the integration kit that you use for your target environment; which one do you use?

Comment: Are you using the SDK?  If so, what type of PingFederate plug-in are you developing (e.g. IdP Adapter, etc.)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I amusing using PingFederate and  Ping One. I have a C# code that gets the environment variable. I want this variable to be the username logged in by ping identity. I was wondering if ping Identity sets any environment variables?

Comment: My website is based on C sharp and it used to get the windows environment variable for username. now I want it changed to the user logged in through ping identity. Is it possible to do so and in that case which SDK should I get (I am assuming the .net integration kit right?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a .NET hosted application on IIS, your application would be considered the Service Provider (SP).  In this architecture PingFederate is the Identity Provider (IdP). This is a brokered authentication design pattern, or more commonly known as Single Sign-On (SSO).  When PingFederate authenticates the user, a token is sent to your application that would contain the username. The code (or library) within your application would process the token and then read out the username.

Here’s a list of options that you could pursue to solve your problem:

1. WS-Federation protocol using the Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) libraries. The config on the PingFederate side is very simple, and you just have to integrate the WIF libraries on your side. Once the WIF libraries and associated web.config configuration is established, you read the claims object passed to your application.
2. OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol using the OWIN middleware. This is also a native MS solution that leverages an open standard. It will require that you have some understanding of OWIN/Katana, as examples are not exactly exhaustive online. PingFedeate supports the OIDC protocol, which is also a very straight forward configuration.
3. PingFederate Agentless Integration Kit. The integration kit is installed on PingFederate and is easy to configure. It is essentially a REST interface between PingFederate and your application to provide a JSON object with the identity information including username.  Your application would need to implement the REST APIs to PingFederate.
4. PingFederate .NET Integration Kit. This solution implements the PingFederate Opentoken solution for exchanging attributes between your app and PingFederate. The .NET code libraries for handling the Opentoken are provided to you by the integration kit, you just have to integrate them into your code baseline along with about 10 lines of code to read the OpenToken to get username. Configuration on PingFederate is simple.

Comment: 5. IIS Integration Kit

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a relief knowing it can be done. Do you think option 4 would be good to go with or do you recommend other options?